# Any way to indentify PAnsiChar using Rtti?

Tags: delphi

I have a method returning a PAnsiChar type. I noticed that Rtti identifies it as a pointer. Is there any way to identify it as a PAnsiChar?

I need the information to return the string from a python extension and python needs to know its a string pointer and not just a void *. The Delphi code for the python is created dynamically hence the need to check what type is returned by my method so I can construct the appropriate code for the python interface.

Comment: No, but you're asking the wrong question. Instead of "Can I find a way to use RTTI to solve a problem?", you should be saying "I have a problem with... How can I...?" and asking for solutions to that question instead.

Comment: Don't quite follow, are you saying don't use Rtti for this problem but redesign my approach so that I don't need Rtti?

Comment: I'm saying that RTTI isn't the only option, and there may be better ones. However, you've limited your question to only RTTI and not asked for a better solution (or provided enough detail for anyone to offer any). You've tied your (and our) hands. (I don't think RTTI can identify a `PAnsiChar` anyway, because it's a generic pointer that happens to point to an `AnsiChar` buffer that's null terminated, and I don't think there's any RTTI associated with it even with the enhancements to RTTI in recent versions of Delphi.)

Comment: That's what I thought, looks like I need to think of some other way. The context is as follows. A dll exposes an API that mirrors an internal object model ( all written in Delphi). There are also a set of simple Rtti methods exposed that allows a user of the dll is figure out details of the exported methods. Another Delphi program loads the dll and generates a Delphi written python extension.

Comment: To avoid a redesign I could define my own PAnsiChar type, eg mypansichar = type PAnsiChar

Comment: Does it make any difference if you have `$TYPEDADDRESS` enabled? I doubt but, but I know that most people run with that disabled. I always run enabled.

Comment: I discovered that the name field of the TRttiType Properties has the name of the type, this includes basic types such as PAnsiChar. I will pose a new question which is what is the semantic difference between the name and the TypeKind.

Comment: @rhody The name is not what you need. My answer explains how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an `TRttiType` instance you do the following:

1. Read the `Handle` property which is a `PTypeInfo`.
2. Check that the `Kind` is `tkPointer`.
3. Then drill down to `TypeData` which is `PTypeData`.
4. Then read out the `RefType` which is type `PPTypeInfo`.
5. Finally check that the type that the pointer refers to is an AnsiChar with `RefType^.Kind=tkChar`.

Put it all together like this:

```
function IsPAnsiChar(AType: TRttiType): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=(AType.Handle.Kind=tkPointer) 
    and (AType.Handle.TypeData.RefType^.Kind=tkChar);
end;
```

And here's a program to demonstrate:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, TypInfo, Rtti;

function IsPAnsiChar(AType: TRttiType): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=(AType.Handle.Kind=tkPointer) 
    and (AType.Handle.TypeData.RefType^.Kind=tkChar);
end;

var
  Context: TRttiContext;

type
  MyPAnsiChar = ^AnsiChar;
  AnsiChar2 = type AnsiChar;
  MyPAnsiChar2 = ^AnsiChar2;

begin
  Writeln(BoolToStr(IsPAnsiChar(Context.GetType(TypeInfo(PAnsiChar))), True));
  Writeln(BoolToStr(IsPAnsiChar(Context.GetType(TypeInfo(MyPAnsiChar))), True));
  Writeln(BoolToStr(IsPAnsiChar(Context.GetType(TypeInfo(MyPAnsiChar2))), True));
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: @rhody Is this answer helpful to you. Some feedback would be nice. What's more, did you notice the discussion of your accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907411/what-is-the-difference-between-rttitype-typekind-and-rttitype-name