# What is the difference between RttiType.TypeKind and RttiType.Name?

Tags: delphi

What is the semantic difference between:

RttiType.TypeKind and RttiType.Name ?

I ask because couldn't one in principle infer the TypeKind from the Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RTTIType.Name`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Rtti.TRttiNamedObject.Name) is a string. [`RTTI.TypeKind`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.TypeKind) is an enumerated type that is suitable for use in a loop or `case` statement. They're not the same at all, and "inferring from a string" is not the same thing at all when it comes to actual use. It's much more clear, concise, and efficient to write

```
case TypeKind of
  tkInteger, tkInt64: DoSomething;
  tkEnumeration: DoThisInstead;
...
```

than it is to write

```
if (Name = 'tkInteger') or (Name = 'tkInt64') then
  DoSomething
else if (Name = 'tkEnumeration') then
  DoThisInstead
...
```

Comment: And less error-prone. It may happen that you write `'tkEnumeraiton'` by mistake, and that will compile just fine. But if you write `tkEnumeraiton` by mistake, the compiler will let you know. The strings are only supposed to be used when communicating with a human (or when writing to a human-readable file format, etc.).

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand: I like your comment, could eliminate unnecessary errors. Ken White: Agreed, code is much clearer and TypeKind can be used in case statements which make it more convenient.

Comment: @Andreas: Good point (I should have mentioned it). Thanks. And congrats, BTW. :-)

Comment: Note that the `Name` property is **not** a string representation of the `TypeKind` property. So the two excerpts that you compare are not comparable.

Comment: @rhody: David's answer is correct, and mine is not. Please unaccept my answer so I can delete it; David's is the one that should be accepted here. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @David: Right you are. I've asked that my answer be unaccepted so that I can delete it.

Comment: @KenWhite Very noble of you

Answer (score 3):

The `TypeKind` and `Name` properties of `TRttiType` are completely different things.

- `TypeKind` tells you what sort of type you have. This can be one of the 23 different options define in the `TTypeKind` enumerated type.
- `Name` tells you which type you have. This is a string and there are an unlimited number of possible values.

Different types will (usually) have different names, but may have the same `TypeKind`. For example consider this simple demonstration.

```
program RttiDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti;

procedure Main;
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  TObjectType, TInterfacedObjectType: TRttiType;
begin
  TObjectType := Context.GetType(TObject);
  TInterfacedObjectType := Context.GetType(TInterfacedObject);
  Writeln(TObjectType.Name);
  Writeln(TInterfacedObjectType.Name);
  Assert(TObjectType.TypeKind=TInterfacedObjectType.TypeKind);
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

The output is:

```
TObject
TInterfacedObject
```

So, you cannot infer the type *kind* from the type *name* since kind and name are quite different things.